# Touch listener not working android

Tags: android

I have a problem with touch listener in my android application. OnTouchLIstenr is not working for the view, i.e ACTION_DOWN is performing well in the listener but ACTION_UP doesnt invokes. i dont know whats the problem going on. But if i set the dummy click listener, both working fine. Why is it so?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {            
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) v;
            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.port);
            }else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar);
            }               
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might consider, returning 'true', since you are handling the touch event.

[Link to a similar question. Answer from adamp, makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756383/what-is-meaning-of-boolean-value-returned-from-an-event-handling-method-in-androi)

Comment: because you are returning false that mean you are saying to system that "touch is not happened"

Comment: On ACTION_DOWN event, the listener is called, but he returns a 'false', which means that the listener is saying : "I don't want to handle any further touch events till ACTION_UP. I have added a link, where this is explained.

Comment: @Hellboy that isn't what the false says! false says I don't want to handle the events, and some other listener below the stack(in case there are multiple views one over the other) can handle.

Comment: Thanks for your good reply guys.. This works fine in the application.

Answer (score 4):

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {            
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) v;
            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.port);
            }else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar);
            }               


       return true;
        }
    });
```

just replace `return true;` instead of `return false;` and check