# Android: OnTouch not working

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I am working on a Multi screen application in Eclispe

I am trying to get the onTouch method to work.

```
package com.example.connectfour;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

final class TrackingTouchListener
implements View.OnTouchListener {

     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {
         Log.d("Testing","Testing");
         switch (evt.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d("Motion Event", "ACTION DOWN");
         if (evt.getX() <= 150)
         {
             Log.d("In the IF", "true");
             return true;
         }
         return false;


}
         Log.d("Not in the IF", "false");
         return false;
}
}
```

This is the code I currently have. It is contained in it's own java file.

At the minute none of the log.d messages appear in logcat. I am assuming this is due to the onTouch event isn't being executed so their is something wrong with my listener. The code in the onTouch isn't importatn I am just trying to get the OnTouch() working at this moment in time

Answer (score 0):

Thing is you are return a `false` instead `true`, returning false means you are saying to system that "touch is not happened"

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756383/what-is-meaning-of-boolean-value-returned-from-an-event-handling-method-in-andro)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use onClickListener instead.