# call ACTION_UP after ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

How to call  `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` after `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` into `setOnTouchListener` of the `Button`

Below is Small Snippets...

```
slide_button_start.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    if(!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){

                        logIt("OUtSide");
                        v.clearFocus();
                        viewPager.bringToFront();

                        return true;

                    }
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                    logIt("Touch...Down");

                    rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());

                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    logIt("UP ha called");
                    return true;

                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Any Answer Appreciated....Thks

Comment: return true when action == ACTION_MOVE

Comment: @pskink Yes , But that didn't call ACTION_UP

Answer (score 1):

It looks like similar issue to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756383/what-is-meaning-of-boolean-value-returned-from-an-event-handling-method-in-andro)

the listener has consumed the event. So ACTION_UP won't be called anymore.

Comment: So what's the Suggestion for That

Comment: try to return false in if condition