# OnTouchListener return value

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I'm trying to understand full the `OnTouchListener`, but I have some doubts.

I have this xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.pablo.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And I have implemented this code i java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

            switch (arg1.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "boton down",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "boton up",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

   }
 }
```

I have read when I return false in `ACTION_DOWN`, the rest of the gesture (`MOVE` and `UP`) doesn't work. But it works in this code, the "up" message is shown on screen, and it shouldn't. So I don't understand completely what is the meaning of the return value in the `OnTouch` event.

Can somebody helps me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756383/what-is-meaning-of-boolean-value-returned-from-an-event-handling-method-in-andro

Comment: O, but if you run the code, you can see the "up" message, and it shouldn't..or not? It's my problem. Thank you

Comment: ACTION_DOWN means you pressed on the button and your finger is still there, then ACTION_UP means you released the button. Of course, the code put there for both actions will execute, because you did both pressing and releasing. This is why the toasts will show on the screen. If you don't want to show the toast for ACTION_UP, just remove the line :P. Returning true from this method will show an animation on the button showing that the buttons was pressed. Returning false will not change the button state, but will execute the code you wrote before the return instruction. Have a good day!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your question is "what does the return value mean on onTouch"?

If you looked at documentation, you would see;

> Returns
>   True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

Comment: Ok, but if you run the above code, yo can see that the "up" message is shown on screen. It shouldn't...