# after finishing touching ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I would like to make an ImageView ? AND WHEN i touch it it change background, when i drag finger far of it it become normal i don't know how to do, thanks

```
 imgButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            cmp++;
            txt2.setText(" " + cmp);
            //Quant on touche l'image :
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                imgButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
            // si Je bouge le dois sur l'image et ....
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                //... et que le doit quitte l'image
                if (event.getX() < 0 || event.getX() > v.getWidth() || event.getY() < 0 || event.getY() > v.getHeight()) {
                    imgButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x00000001, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }
                if (event.getX() > 0 && event.getX() < v.getWidth() && event.getY() > 0 && event.getY() < v.getHeight()) {
                    // ... et que le doit revient vers L'image
                    imgButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                }
            }
            // Si je lève le doits et...
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // .... sur l'image :
                if (event.getX() > 0 && event.getX() < v.getWidth() && event.getY() > 0 && event.getY() < v.getHeight()) {
                    //Finger back to the view
                    imgButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x00000001, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, game.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unclear. Why don't you use the usual click listener, instead?

Comment: that's what i want to do :
i have Image View and when i touch it,  it takes effect like changing ColorFilter (to inform user that the button is touched) and when i drag finger far of the image it becomes normal (to inform user that the image is not being touched ) and again when i drag finger near to the imgView it take again effects,

Comment: It seems to me that you indeed want a state list selector, on a normal click. No "drag, close, far, touch, non touch, ...". Just clicked or non clicked. With visual feedback.

Comment: I think that is it. i want to make the imageView behavior with pressing and touching like in buttons of application we see on playsore, How to do that, Sorry for bad english :D

Comment: The answer from @SachinS is nearly good. Just that I would have used separate file for the items and used a default case for the not pressed state, rather than using pressed="false". Reference: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **getActionMasked()** rather than **getAction()**.

**getAction()** returns the action with pointer information while **getActionMasked()** only returns the simple action, which makes the action comparison work correctly.

Then catch the right action in the **onTouch** method.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //Finger down
        //Change the color
    }
    if(event.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if(event.getX()<0 || event.getX()>v.getWidth() || event.getY()<0 || event.getY()>v.getHeight()){
            //Finger exit the view
            //Change the color back
        }
    }
    if(event.getActionMasked()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        //Finger up
        //Change the color back
    }
    return true;
}
```

The returned value should be **true** in most cases. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756383/what-is-meaning-of-boolean-value-returned-from-an-event-handling-method-in-andro).

Comment: Thank you that was helpful ;)
But what if i'm still touching and go back to image view and make action Up on it, logically the event Onclick must be triggered how to do this

Comment: In action up, add an if statement to check whether finger is in the view (just like I do in action move). Then use View's callOnClick() method to trigger onClick event manually.

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file under drawable folder named`change.xml` of your application and put below codes.Modify it  with your color codes.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <color android:color="#00FF00"/>
   </item>
   <item android:state_pressed="false">
      <color android:color="#00FFFF"/>
   </item>
</selector>
```

and add the below attribute to your ImageView of your layout

```
android:background="@drawable/change"
```

Comment: Done , But now what should i do in the MainActivity.java , it is the first time i use this method so what should i do in code ?

Comment: remove the setOnTouchListener,no need for that

Comment: what about the answer?

Comment: When i click on the image nothing changes, i created change.xml and write the code u have proposed, and added attribute < android:background="@drawable/change" > in imageView in content_main.xml , and in java code i just let two function super.oncreate and setcontentview(content_main). But Finally i got what i wanted by just Code Java , see the question , i have modified the code  there, but i'm still asking why your Answer does not work for me ?

Comment: I had to add Attribute android:clickable="true" that what was missed Thank you all ;)