# application blank after move to another fragment using bottom navigation view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley, bottomnavigationview

I tried to build an app that have 5 fragment that displayed using bottom navigation view. I use volley to get the data from database. i have a problem with calling the data. at fragment A. i call the web service and got some data and then display it using recyclerview. But if i move to another fragment ( lets say fragment B) and went back to the fragment A. the data is lost and it just show the standard ui like search widget,spinner widget. All i want to ask is :

1. where should i put the code to call web service for all my fragment. On the activity that handle the fragment or just on the fragment?
2. why volley doesn't call data again when i back to the fragment?

this is the code of my mainactivity that contain bottom navigation view with 5 fragments:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(isNetworkStatusAvialable (getApplicationContext())) {
        bottomNavigationView=(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
        frameLayout=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);

        herbal= new herbal();
        crude = new crude();
        database=new database();
        analysis=new analysis();
        compound=new compound();

        setFragment(herbal);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.nav_herbal:
                        setFragment(herbal);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_crude:
                        setFragment(crude);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_database:
                        setFragment(database);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_analysis:
                        setFragment(analysis);
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_compound:
                        setFragment(compound);
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;

                }
            }


        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "internet is not avialable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}

private boolean isNetworkStatusAvialable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager != null)
    {
        NetworkInfo netInfos = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netInfos != null)
            if(netInfos.isConnected())
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

this is the example in my fragment which calling web service and then display it using recycler view:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_herbal, container, false);
        herbalModels = new ArrayList<>();
        kampoModels = new ArrayList<>();

        searchHerbal = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.search_herbal);
        searchHerbal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchHerb();
            }
        });
        loadData = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadRecyclerView);
        RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        sortData(rootView);
        get20DataJamu();
        get20DataKampo();
        StartRecyclerViewJamu(rootView);


        return rootView;

    }


    private void searchHerb() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        searchHerbs searchHerbs = new searchHerbs();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_frame, searchHerbs);
        ft.commit();
    }


    private void StartRecyclerViewKampo(View rootView) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_herbal);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        kampoAdapter = new kampoAdapter(mRecyclerView, getActivity(), kampoModels);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(kampoAdapter);
        kampoAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                kampoModels.add(null);
                kampoAdapter.notifyItemInserted(kampoModels.size() - 1);
                handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        kampoModels.remove(kampoModels.size() - 1);
                        kampoAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(kampoModels.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = kampoModels.size();
                        int end = start + 20;
                        loadMoreKampo(start, end);
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadMoreKampo(final int start, final int end) {
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onresponse" + jsonArray.toString());
                        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                kampoModels.add(
                                        new kampoModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("albumId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("thumbnailUrl")
                                        )
                                );
                                kampoAdapter.notifyItemInserted(kampoModels.size());

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }
                        kampoAdapter.setLoaded();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onerror" + volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    private void get20DataKampo() {
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onresponsekampo" + jsonArray.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "lengthresponse" + jsonArray.length());
                        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                kampoModels.add(
                                        new kampoModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("albumId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("thumbnailUrl")
                                        )
                                );

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onerrorkampo" + volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

    }


    private void StartRecyclerViewJamu(final View rootView) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_herbal);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // create an Object for Adapter
        mAdapter = new herbalAdapter(mRecyclerView, getActivity(), herbalModels);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        loadData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                herbalModels.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(herbalModels.size() - 1);
                handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        herbalModels.remove(herbalModels.size() - 1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(herbalModels.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = herbalModels.size();
                        int end = start + 20;
                        loadMoreJamu(start, end);

                    }
                }, 5000);

            }
        });


    }

    private void get20DataJamu() {

        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onresponse" + jsonArray.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "lengthonresponse" + jsonArray.length());

                        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                herbalModels.add(
                                        new herbalModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("userId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("body")
                                        )
                                );

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onerror" + volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);
    }


    private void loadMoreJamu(final int start, final int end) {
        String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onresponse" + jsonArray.toString());
                        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
//                                Log.d(TAG,"jsonobject"+jsonObject);
                                herbalModels.add(
                                        new herbalModel(
                                                jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                                "Khasiat",
                                                jsonObject.getString("userId"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("id"),
                                                jsonObject.getString("body")
                                        )
                                );
                                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(herbalModels.size());
                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                            }
                        }
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Onerror" + volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

    }

    private void sortData(final View rootView) {

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.filter_herbal);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        List<categoriesHerbal> itemList = new ArrayList<categoriesHerbal>();
        itemList.add(
                new categoriesHerbal(
                        "1",
                        "Jamu"
                )
        );
        itemList.add(
                new categoriesHerbal(
                        "2",
                        "Kampo"
                )
        );
        ArrayAdapter<categoriesHerbal> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<categoriesHerbal>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemList);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    categoriesHerbal selectedValue = (categoriesHerbal) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String categories = (String) selectedValue.getCategories();
                    String idCategories = (String) selectedValue.getIdCategories();
                    StartRecyclerViewJamu(rootView);

                } else {
                    categoriesHerbal selectedValue = (categoriesHerbal) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String categories = (String) selectedValue.getCategories();
                    String idCategories = (String) selectedValue.getIdCategories();
                    StartRecyclerViewKampo(rootView);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**move your data code in separate class and call it wherever needed.**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
switch (menuItem.getItemId())
{
    case R.id.nav_herbal:
        setFragment(herbal);
        return true;

    case R.id.nav_crude:
        setFragment(crude);
        return true;

    case R.id.nav_database:
        setFragment(database);
        return true;

    case R.id.nav_analysis:
        setFragment(analysis);
        return true;

    case R.id.nav_compound:
        setFragment(compound);
        return true;

    /*default:
        return false;*/  //no need for this one

}
return true; /*you forget'it*/
}
```

Comment: what is return true for ? the one that i forget

Comment: onNavigationItemSelected has return type Boolean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756383/what-is-meaning-of-boolean-value-returned-from-an-event-handling-method-in-andro

Comment: is that can resolve my problem ? i already change that but it still the same

Comment: i think its all about life cycle or on fragment.replace..but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: you have to give more information in more organized way.